# Continuous image of a locally connected space which is not locally connected

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

The question is pretty much in the title, I'm looking for an example of a locally connected space and continuous mapping such that the image is not locally connected.

Thanks!

EDIT: Corrected the phrasing to the intended meaning.

Comment: Did you want some condition on the image of the map? Otherwise, pick any non-locally connected space and any map from a single point to this space.

Comment: The identity from $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology to the Sorgenfry Line.

Comment: @James: The image $f(U)$ need not be open unless the map $f$ is an open mapping.

Comment: See my answer to the question [Is the image of a path or arc locally path/arc connected?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351087/is-the-image-of-a-path-or-arc-locally-path-arc-connected). It shows that even the continuous image of the unit interval need not be locally connected.

Comment: May be the following will work. Let $X=[0;1]$ and $f:X\to\mathbb C$ such that $f(x)=xe^{i/x}$ for each $x\in X$.

Comment: Thanks to David and Stefan for the counterexamples. 
Also just out of curiosity I'm wondering why someone voted this down? (So I could correct the issue or refrain from doing so again in the future)

Comment: I just realised that I had voted down your question. Must have accidentally clicked the button. Fortunately, I could just retag the question ( and this tag even fits the question :-) ) and then I was able to withdraw the downvote. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the following variant on the [topologist's sine curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

[image]

This space $X$ consists of the graph of $y = \sin(\pi/x)$ for $0<x<1$, together with a closed arc from the point $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$.  Note that $X$ is not locally connected at $(0,0)$.

However, there exists a continuous surjection $f\colon [0,2)\to X$.  Specifically, $f(0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1) = (1,0)$, with $f(t)$ following along the bottom curve for $0\leq t\leq 1$.  For $t>1$, the function follows along the sine curve, i.e.
$$
f(t) \;=\; \left(2-t,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2-t}\right)\right)\qquad\text{for }t> 1.
$$

Comment: Another nice example. I really liked that graph, is there a simple way to create such graphs?  :)

Comment: I borrowed the picture from [a previous answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/135483/1726).  I don't recall how I made it, but I would guess *Mathematica*.

Comment: why is X not connected in (0,0)? isnt it that neighbor of X is not separable?

Answer (score 27):

Boring example: any space $X$ is the continuous image of the discrete topology on $X$ (using the identity and noting that any function with a discrete domain is continuous). A discrete space is trivially locally connected (all singleton sets). Now let $X$ be *any* non-locally connected space.

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider $X = \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ under discrete topology and $Y = \{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ as subspace  of real line $\mathbb{R}$.
Define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(0)=0,f(n)=\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}$.Then $f$ is a bijection. and $f$ is continuous. Therefore, $Y$ is continuous image of $X$. Note that $X$ is being a discrete space is locally connected but $Y$ is not locally connected.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please, [learn some typesetting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Moreover, if $f:X\to Y$, why define it in $0$?

Answer (score 0):

The graph-parametrisation of the graph of $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ ?  Instead of letting the graph trail off to the right as $x\to\infty$, just turn it around and let the curve run along the interval $[-1,1]$ on the $y$-axis.  Then every point of this interval will have the property that local connectivity fails.

Comment: Maybe this is more reasonable as a comment?

Comment: What? That graph is locally connected.

Comment: It seems that the graph of $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ is homeomorhic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I added the part of the curve along the $y$-axis.