# A kind of converse to the Jordan curve theorem

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

The Jordan curve theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ says that if $S$ is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $S$ splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ into exactly two connected components $A$ and $B$.

I was thinking about a kind of converse to this problem which is as follows.

Let $S$ be a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S$. Define

$$A:=\{a\in\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S: a\text{ and } x \text{ are path connected in } \mathbb{R}^2\setminus S\}$$

$$B:=\{b\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S: b\text{ and } y\text{ are path connected in }\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S\}$$

If $A\cap B=\emptyset$ does there exists a connected $T\subset S$  such that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus T$ is split into exactly two connected components one which contains $A$ and the other that contains $B$.

Any help or references on this would be much appreciated

Note: Ive made an edit to reflect the comments using the topologists sine curve. I believe that now this will not be a counter-example because the 'quasi-circle" is obviously connected. Also I apologize for not being more specific originally.

Comment: It follows from Alexander duality that the fundamental group of S is non-trivial, at least, and has elements of infinite order.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment,  Is this saying that there is a closed loop in S that is not contractible to either x or y

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But Alexander duality works only if $S$ is locally contractible, no?

Comment: R.L. Moore's student J.R. Kline gave a characterization of such sets $T$ back in 1917 in this paper http://www.jstor.org/stable/1988859?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. Perhaps this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. I feel like if this were not true it would have an off the shelf example

Answer (score 11):

Consider this variant of the extended topologist's sine curve:

[image]

(picture borrowed from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429164/continuous-image-of-a-locally-connected-space-which-is-not-locally-connected))
It is the closure of the graph of the function $x\mapsto \sin(\pi/x)$ defined on the half open interval $(0,1]$ with the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ connected by a simple arc. It is a closed and bounded subset $S$ of $\mathbf R^2$. Its complement has exactly $2$ path-wise connected components, but there is no simple closed curve $T$ contained in $S$.

Comment: So Thank you for the example. I Should have specified more clearly. These "infinite closed curves" actually work fine in my setting, and I didn't know of any way to exclude them.
Could you maybe comment on the viability of the following method. Instead of requiring T to be a closed curve. Instead require that T is a connected set that splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ into exactly two regions one that contains A and the other that contains B.
The example above is connected (not path connected) and so would work under this new definition right?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Modify the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist's_sine_curve) to construct a counter example to your conjecture. The true statement is that $\check{H}^1(R^2 -S)$ is nonzero (by the Alexander duality).

**Edit.** This is a partial answer to the latest version of the question. (The accepted answer by Lukas does not really settle the problem.)

First, some definitions. A **continuum** is a metrizable compact connected set. (If you do  not know what metrizable means, just think of a subset of $R^n$.) A **[Lakes of Wada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada)** continuum is a continuum $C$ in $R^2$  which has empty interior and whose complement consists of more than 2 components $A_i$ such that the boundary of each $A_i$ is $C$. At the first glance, such thing is impossible; take a look at the Wikipedia picture to get some idea of what it looks like.

Now, suppose that $T\subset C$ is a proper closed subset of a Lakes of Wada continuum $C$. Pick a point $p\in C - T$. Then, since $p$ lies on the boundary of all components of $R^2 - C$ it follows that $R^2 -T$ is connected as all components of $R^2-C$ can be connected to $p$ by paths disjoint from $T$. The conclusion is that such $C$ cannot contain a closed subset whose complement in $R^2$ consists of exactly two components.

This means that the answer to Daniel's question is negative if one also requires $T\subset S$ to be closed. (And the subset constructed in Lukas' answer is closed!) As for noncompact connected subsets, I am not sure, but if I were to bet, I would guess that the answer is again negative.

You can find more and references in

*History of continuum theory,* by J.Charatonik, in "Handbook of the History of General Topology", Vol. 2.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a counterexample which I think works.

$S \subset \Bbb R^2$ be the subspace consisting of points $(x, \sin(1/x))$ for $x \in (0, 1]$ and points in $\{0\} \times [-1, 1]$ union an arc joining $(0, 0)$ with $(1, \sin(1))$, namely, the *quasi-circle*.

$S$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^2$. One can see that $S$ separates $\Bbb R^2$ into two disjoint components by noting that image of any path $\gamma$ not hitting $S$ has a positive distance from $S$, as both are compact subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$. Then one can - with care - replace the $\{0\} \times [-1, 1]$ part of $S$ (because $\gamma$ has distance at least $\delta > 0$ from it) to turn it into a circle and invoke Jordan curve theorem.

However, there is no such $T$: any closed loop in $S$ must miss the origin $(0, 0)$ as $S$ is not path connected at that point. But then obviously such loops do not separate $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks to @DanielFischer for the proof of separation of the quasi-circle.

Comment: An exercise in Engelking, General Topology, is to show that $\{(x,\sin 1/x ):x\in (0,1]\}\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1])$  is connected but not path-connected. from which it follows that the quasi-circle is not a continuous image of [0,1],  so it is not a closed loop.

Comment: Yes but if we instead remove the point that T is a closed loop and instead impose that it is a connected set which splits the space into two regions will this be true